# Simplified Travelling Salesman in Prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking, traveling-salesman, prolog-dif

I've looked through the similar questions but can't find anything that's relevant to my problem. I'm struggling to find an algorithm or set of 'loops' that will find a path from `CityA` to `CityB`, using a database of

```
distance(City1,City2,Distance)
```

facts. What I've managed to do so far is below, but it always backtracks at `write(X),` and then completes with the final iteration, which is what I want it to do but only to a certain extent.

For example, I don't want it to print out any city names that are dead ends, or to use the final iteration. I want it to basically make a path from `CityA` to `CityB`, writing the name of the cities it goes to on the path.

I hope somebody can help me!

```
all_possible_paths(CityA, CityB) :-
    write(CityA),
    nl,
    loop_process(CityA, CityB).

loop_process(CityA, CityB) :- 
    CityA == CityB.
loop_process(CityA, CityB) :-
    CityA \== CityB,
    distance(CityA, X, _),
    write(X),
    nl,
    loop_process(X, CityB).
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to demonstrate how you can achieve what you're working on so that you can understand better how it works. So since your OP wasn't very complete, I took some liberties ! Here are the facts I'm working with :

```
road(birmingham,bristol, 9).
road(london,birmingham, 3).
road(london,bristol, 6).
road(london,plymouth, 5).
road(plymouth,london, 5).
road(portsmouth,london, 4).
road(portsmouth,plymouth, 8).
```

Here is the predicate we will call to find our paths, **get_road/4**. It basically calls the working predicate, that has two accumulators (one for the points already visited and one for the distance we went through).

```
get_road(Start, End, Visited, Result) :-
    get_road(Start, End, [Start], 0, Visited, Result).
```

Here is the working predicate,
**get_road/6** : get_road(+Start, +End, +Waypoints, +DistanceAcc, -Visited, -TotalDistance) :
The first clause tells that if there is a road between our first point and our last point, we can end here.

```
get_road(Start, End, Waypoints, DistanceAcc, Visited, TotalDistance) :-
    road(Start, End, Distance),
    reverse([End|Waypoints], Visited),
    TotalDistance is DistanceAcc + Distance.
```

The second clause tells that if there is a road between our first point and an intermediate point, we can take it and then solve get_road(intermediate, end).

```
get_road(Start, End, Waypoints, DistanceAcc, Visited, TotalDistance) :-
    road(Start, Waypoint, Distance),
    \+ member(Waypoint, Waypoints),
    NewDistanceAcc is DistanceAcc + Distance,
    get_road(Waypoint, End, [Waypoint|Waypoints], NewDistanceAcc, Visited, TotalDistance).
```

Usage is as follows :

```
?- get_road(portsmouth, plymouth, Visited, Distance).
```

And yields :

```
Visited = [portsmouth, plymouth],
Distance = 8 ;
Visited = [portsmouth, london, plymouth],
Distance = 9 ;
Visited = [portsmouth, plymouth, london, plymouth],
Distance = 18 ;
false.
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: You sir, have gone above and beyond the call of duty! This is incredible, it is perfect and it actually makes sense! Sorry I'm such a dummy, I'm really new to prolog and while quite a lot of it has come very naturally I've really struggled with this task. Thank you so much so so sooooo much :]

Comment: do not hesitate to post further questions if you struggle again to understand this code, I or others will answer them in comments :)

Comment: @m09 I really loved your approach to this problem, but I wanted to know how would you tackle it if instead of having a Start and End point, the Salesman had to pass through a set of cities inside the full scope of cities and return to the place he started.

Answer (score 4):

Please separate the pure part from the impure (I/O, like `write/1`, `nl/0` but also `(==)/2` and `(\==)/2`). As long as they are entirely interlaced with your pure code you cannot expect much.

Probably you want a relation between a starting point, an end point and a path in between.

Should that path be acyclic <strike>or do you permit cycles</strike>?

To ensure that an element `X` does not occur in a list `Xs` use the goal `maplist(dif(X),Xs).`
You do not need any further auxiliary predicates to make this a nice relation!

Comment: Once a city has been used, it cannot be used again in the same path. So, acyclic. Also what do you mean by pure and impure?

Comment: I added an explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a successful list as an Out variable in all_possible_paths. Then write out that list. Don't do both in the same procedure.